# Mongoose search in object

Tags: mongoose, schema

I am trying to build a search bar on my front end.  I would like this search bar to loop through an object and if it finds a match, return the value found.

Basically I have this:

```
theSchema.find({
            $and: [
                { company: String(company)},
                { user: String(user) },
                {
                    $or: [
                        { 'information.field1': { $regex: String(search), $options: "i" } },
                        { 'information.field2': { $regex: String(search), $options: "i" } },
                        { 'information.field3': { $regex: String(search), $options: "i" } },
                        { 'information.field4': { $regex: String(search), $options: "i" } },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
.then(result => result)
```

And this is my schema:

```
const theSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    information: {
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        default: {}
    },
    ...

})
```

So I am trying to loop through my `information` object and search all the fields in there.

What I currently have is a bit impractical for obvious reasons.  I don't want to amend the search every time a new field is added to the object, and not all documents in the schema have all of the fields.

I tried looking at the `$in` operator, but that looks to work for arrays.

Is there any way to search all of the fields in an object?

Comment: Maybe you need to use aggregation in this case